# Password Policy on Openldap doesn't support all attributes

Tags: password, openldap

So far, I discovered "**pwdminlength**" attribute in password policy doesn't work when OpenLDAP uses SHA or crypt options as password modification techniques. Though, it does work with clear-text. This is really bad, because as a system admin we cannot ask users to modify their passwords with clear-text option.

Does anyone have other alternatives for this password policy to work correctly even with the "**pwdminlength**" attribute?

Answer (score 1):

The `pwdMinLength` attribute *can* be enforced but provided the user uses the LDAPv3 Password Modify (RFC 3062) extended operation to set their password, i.e. what the tool `ldappasswd` does. This way the server will see the clear password prior to storing it as an encrypted value using whatever hashing scheme is chosen.

By also setting the `pwdCheckQuality` attribute to `2` in the policy object the server will reject any value it cannot verify thereby stopping users from updating the attribute to a hashed value.

Comment: understood. thanks very much having look at this.